# Adding computed column extremely slow

Tags: mysql-5.7, computed-column

We are trying to add computed column to a table and this operation is taking more than 20 hours to complete:

```
json_unquote(coalesce(json_extract(`int_data`,'$.Item.IRefNum'),
    json_extract(`m_dt`,'$.refId')))
```

Database: MySQL verison 5.7
Table rows: 32,636,254

The table already exists with data in it and can't be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `STORED` generated column causes table re-creation (copy).

From [Generated Column Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-generated-column-operations) in the documentation:

> **Table 14.13 Online DDL Support for Generated Column Operations**
>
> | Operation | In Place | Rebuilds Table | Permits Concurrent DML | Only Modifies Metadata |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Adding a STORED column | No | Yes | No | No |
> | Modifying STORED column order | No | Yes | No | No |
> | Dropping a STORED column | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |
> | Adding a VIRTUAL column | Yes | No | Yes | Yes |
> | Modifying VIRTUAL column order | No | Yes | No | No |
> | Dropping a VIRTUAL column | Yes | No | Yes | Yes |

Try making the column `VIRTUAL` instead:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
    ADD COLUMN column_name column_datatype 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (column_expression) VIRTUAL,
    ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```